# Setting max-file-size for multipart uploads in spring boot does not work with 50MB limit

Tags: java, spring-boot, upload, multipartform-data

I'm using SpringBoot v.2.3.0.RELEASE

I have a multipart RESTapi and I need to limit the size of the uploaded file.

So, I added these properties into my application.properties file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

This works fine using 10MB limit but, If I change the values from 10MB to 50MB this do not works.
In this case I did't receive any errors and the API works fine but, obviously I need to limit this upload.

I noticed that the limits sill works with values less 50MB (for example with 49MB are ok).

Is there some reason? Need I to add some other properties?

Answer (score 0):

In my current Spring project I configure a bean with a custom `MultipartResolver` which explicitly sets the maximum upload size.  For a file limit of 10MB and a total upload size limit of 50MB, you could use:

```java
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(10000000);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50000000);

    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Define this bean in Spring config class, which you may already have created somewhere (and if not, then create one to hold you bean definitions).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is this a workaround? Are there some bugs into Spring code about the usage of the max-upload-size properties?

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround, and I had the same exact issue you were having.  What I wrote above worked for me, not sure if it would also work for you.  Give it a try and find out.

Comment: Do I need to add something into my pom as external lib?

Comment: Are you using a modern IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse?  If so, it should handle that for you.